# Menu links URL with PHP GET method

Tags: menus, urls, links

Hello the community,

I would like to know if is it possible to generate menu links using the PHP Get Method instead of the regural one used in Wordpress? e.g :

*www.mybeautifulwebsite.com/category/sport?sport=football*

instead of

*www.mybeautifulwebsite.com/category/sport/football*

**Explanation:**

My page about sports news list 1 news per sport, like this:

[image: Sports News]

My page about a particular sport news list all of its news, like this:

[image: Football News]

As you can see, it's quite the same page. So I want to reuse my page about "Sports News" to display the news about each sport.

**For information:**

Football, Basket-ball, ... are sub-categories of the Sport category

I registered my sport sub-menu via register_nav_menus() in my functions.php and called it via wp_nav_menu() in my category-sport.php.

I think I can create this sub-menu manually or create my menu with custom links to do what I want, but:

1. I want to know if there is a more beautiful way to do it
2. I want to know if my way of thinking is good because I'm new in Wordpress development

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `GET` parameters rather than `POST` parameters? A `POST` request doesn't add things to the URL as it sends parameters in the HTTP headers

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion. I edit my question.

Comment: Why do you need to use a GET parameter. The second URL in your question will automatically list the posts that you want. It’s the default behaviour.

Comment: Yes I'm agree but the archive pages for my Sport sub-categories need to be a little bit customized and not just list the posts like my "Health" archive for example. So, I thought of several solutions: **1.** Customize my archive.php file **2.** Create one category-$slug.php file for each sport, like I did for the Sport page **3.** Find another way like the one I proposed. Maybe I'm totally wrong with the Wordpress mindset, just let me know. PS: The sub-menu will be only shown on the Sport main page and each Sport pages

Comment: Option 2 sounds better, you can always check the queried object ( `get_queried_object()` ) in the template to get the data, there's no need to change the URL and use `$_GET`

Comment: Ok thank you guys for your support. I will use the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.
After a little search with the intention to find a way to re-use my category template (Sport), I found the solution of my problem: [Force sub-categories to use the parent category template](http://werdswords.com/force-sub-categories-use-the-parent-category-template/)

So I let this solution here in case of someone has the same problem and the same <strike>weird</strike> idea to resolve it than me.